# order vector or POSIXct not working

Tags: r

I have a vector of POSIXct elements and I want to sort them descending but it is not working. Here is a toy model. I cannot simply reverse the order of the indicies because the dates are not sorted in any order.

input:

```
    dateTime<- as.POSIXct(c("2014-10-27 12:31:01 PDT","2014-10-27 14:59:01 PDT","2014-10-27 05:45:01 PDT"))
    class(dateTime)
sort(as.POSIXlt(dateTime),descending = TRUE)
sort(as.POSIXlt(dateTime), descending= FALSE)
```

output:

> sort(as.POSIXlt(dateTime),descending = TRUE)
>   [1] "2014-10-27 05:45:01 PDT" "2014-10-27 12:31:01 PDT" "2014-10-27 14:59:01 PDT"
>
> sort(as.POSIXlt(dateTime), descending= FALSE)
>   [1] "2014-10-27 05:45:01 PDT" "2014-10-27 12:31:01 PDT" "2014-10-27 14:59:01 PDT"

You can see that descending does not seem to work.

any help?

Comment: No need to use `as.POSIXlt`. It would just be wasteful coding unless there is some unstated reason for using it.

Comment: The `POSIXlt` was my doing.  I made a mistake in my first answer.  OP originally had `as.POSIXct`

Answer (score 2):

The argument is named `decreasing`, and you wrote `descending`

```
args(sort)
# function (x, decreasing = FALSE, ...) 
# NULL
sort(dateTime)
# [1] "2014-10-27 05:45:01 PDT" "2014-10-27 12:31:01 PDT"
# [3] "2014-10-27 14:59:01 PDT"
sort(dateTime, decreasing = TRUE)
# [1] "2014-10-27 14:59:01 PDT" "2014-10-27 12:31:01 PDT"
# [3] "2014-10-27 05:45:01 PDT"
```

I've made the same mistake many times.  When you pass `decreasing` as an argument, it gets passed to `...` and ends up going unused.

Comment: Thanks. What is POSIXlt vs POSIXct?  Why wouldn't h the sort work because the class(dateTime) says POSIXct

Comment: - Actually that code dos not seem to work see the edit.

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain, but there is a lot of information in `?POSIXlt`

Comment: Can you take a look at the edit. I am getting different results

Comment: There may be no separate sort method for 'POSIXct' objects but that doesn't mean that `sort` will not succeed. 'POSIXct' objects inherit operational capacities from numeric and comparison operators, and so `sort` gives completely expected results.

Comment: @BondedDust - Right, I've corrected that.  Cheers.  Looks like I need to do a bit of reading myself :)